# Как получить дробную часть у числа с плавающей запятой?

Tags: c

Подскажите, не могу понять.
Есть код

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float money;

    do
    {
        printf ("How much change should I give you?\n");
        money = GetFloat();
    }
    while (money<0);

    printf("%.2f\n", money);
}
```

Как можно извлечь из переменной float знаки после запятой?

Comment: что значит извлечь? вы хотите получить только дробную часть?

Comment: да, только дробную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию `modf`. Стоит учитывать, что знак дробной части будет такой же как знак исходного числа. Для отрицательных чисел, дробная часть будет отрицательной.

```
float money;
double fractpart, intpart;

money = 8.12;
fractpart = modf(money, &intpart);

printf("Integral part = %lf\n", intpart);
printf("Fraction Part = %lf \n", fractpart);
```

Comment: для отрицательных может работать немного неожиданно. Да и `money - (int)money` как-то привычнее...

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под неожиданно?

Comment: отрицательная дробная часть например. Как бы многие знакомые с математикой предполагают, что дробная часть строго меньше 1 и больше или равна 0.

Comment: добавил это в ответ.

Comment: спасибо всем!!!!

Comment: Судя по идентификатору "money", речь идёт о рублях, долларах и т.д. А Вы хотите получить копейки, центы и т.д... Так вот, использование float для хранения денежнх значений - это плохая идея. Это ОЧЕНЬ плохая идея. Дело в том, что правила арифметики, принятые в бухгалтерских вычислениях (в частности - для округления денежных значений) сильно не совпадают с правилами округления для обычной математики и, тем более, для плавающей точки.

Я не буду  вдаваться в подробности -  это большая и сложная тема. Во времена СССР даже существовал специальный ГОСТ по этому поводу.